# Common term for the "value-based" OR operator

Tags: c++, c, perl, language-agnostic

Just a quick question

```
 printf("%d", 99 || 44) prints "1" in C
 print 99 || 44 prints "99" in perl
```

There are two different kinds of evaluation.  Does each one have a name?

edit: i'm interested to know how this Perl evaluation is commonly called when compared to C. When you say "C example is X, and perl example is not X, but Y" which words would you use for X and Y. "short circuit" is not what i'm looking for.

Comment: A common term for two operations that have different effects? Isn't this like asking if there's a common term for apples and oranges? Seems a bit contradictory.

Comment: @Jalf: He is asking for a _common term for these two kinds of **evaluation**_ , shouldn't the answer be "Short Circuit Evaluation" ?

Comment: I'm not sure. Is short circuit evaluation the trait he's interested in? It could just as well be "logical or", or "int-to-bool conversion". The two lines of code have a lot in common, but there are also some major differences. I'm not really sure what the OP wants a common term *for*

Comment: From the title, I'd guess you are looking for a name for the second type of || to distinguish it from the first, but from the body of your question I'd guess you want a common name that encompasses both.  Which is it?  And can you change either the title or body to make it more clear what you are asking?

Comment: How can it be 'language-agnostic', 'C', 'C++', and 'Perl' ?

Comment: No. "Fruit" also covers bananas and peaches.

Comment: @stereofrog: change the topic - a german typically translates "common" to "üblich", which is used in wrong way, here it means "gemeinsam"!! you want to use "typical" instead of "common"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The C version uses || as the logical OR between the two values. Both 44 and 99 evaluate to `true` in C as they are not `0`, so the result of an OR between them returns `1` (AKA `true` in C)

<s>In that particular perl snippet, || is the [null-coalescing operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_coalescing_operator), an binary which evaluates to the second argument if the first is null, otherwise evaluating to the first argument. Since `99` is the first argument and not null, it gets returned and printed.</s>

EDIT: Thanks Evan for the clafication: The || operator in perl is not the null-coalescing operator, it returns the RHS if the LHS evaluates to false, other wise returning the LHS. `//` is the "proper" null-coalescing operator.

Here's the list of values in perl that evaluate to false ([from wikipedia)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perl)

```
$false = 0; # the number zero
$false = 0.0; # the number zero as a float
$false = 0b0; # the number zero in binary
$false = 0x0; # the number zero in hexadecimal
$false = '0'; # the string zero
$false = ""; # the empty string
$false = undef; # the return value from undef
$false = 2-3+1  # computes to 0 which is converted to "0" so it is false
```

Comment: re: *In that particular perl snippet, || is the null-coalescing operator, an binary which evaluates to the second argument if the first is null* -- It most certainly is **NOT** null-coalescing. Yes, `undef || die` will die, but so will `0 || die`. `||` evaluates the LHS and if it returns false it evaluates the RHS. undef just so happens to evaluate to false (thank god). Conversely, `//` is the null-coalescing operator introduced in 5.10 which *will* only trigger the RHS if the LHS is null, prior to that you could do `(defined $a) || die`

Comment: *The || operator in perl is not the null-coalescing operator, it returns the LHS if the first evaluates to false, other wise returning the first argument.* Actually, like all statements in Perl it returns its last evaluated expression which is always the last argument with `||`. Check out this `perl -e'print 0||"0"||undef'` to see.

Answer (score 8):

Read [here](http://www.perl.com/doc/manual/html/pod/perlop.html#C_style_Logical_And).

> Binary || performs a **short-circuit** logical OR operation. That is, if the left operand is true, the right operand is not even evaluated. Scalar or list context propagates down to the right operand if it is evaluated.
>
> In Perl the || and && operators differ from C's in that, rather than returning 0 or 1, they return the last value evaluated.

---

> printf("%d", 99 || 44) prints "1" in C

That is because `99||44` returns true(only 99(which is non-zero) is evaluated due to the short-circuiting action of `||` ) whose equivalent is `1` hence `printf()` prints `1`.

> print 99 || 44 prints "99" in perl

..rather than returning 0 or 1, the last value evaluated(`99` here) is returned.

Comment: @stereofrog: Your question was _is there a **common term** for these two kinds of evaluation?_ .My answer is Short-Circuit evaluation. Doesn't it answer your question? BTW whoever downvoted, please explain the reason?

Comment: stereofrog: Look again, he answered, the difference is an implementation detail.  C returns 1 for "true", while perl returns the last non-zero value it evaluates for "true".

Answer (score 8):

As you note, the words you are looking for are *not* "short-circuit".  Short-circuit evaluation means that in the expression

```
e1 || e2
```

if expression `e1` is evaluated to something representing truth, then it is not necessary to evaluate `e2`.  Both C and Perl use short-circuit evaluation.

I'm aware of the distinction you make in *two different flavors of short-circuit OR*, but in twenty years of working in programming languages I have never seen these things named.  The Perl version is quite popular in dynamic languages, e.g., Icon, Lua, Scheme.

The Perl version is *almost* expressible in C:

```
e1 ? e1 : e2
```

Unfortunately this version may evaluate `e1` twice, depending on the optimizer—and if `e1` has side effects, or if the compiler can't tell if it *might* have side effects, then the compiler is *required* to evaluated it twice.   This defect can be fixed by binding the value of `e1` to a fresh local variable, but that requires a GNU extension.

The C behavior can be emulated in Perl by

```
!!(e1 || e2)
```

Answer (score 3):

In Perl, `99 || 44` returns `99`, because `||` is "short circuiting" and if its first argument is true in boolean context, it just returns it. `print` prints 99.

In C the result of `||` is logical, which passed to `printf` results either in 1 or 0. It's also short-circuiting, so 44 isn't even evaluated.

Comment: C's || is short-circuiting as well. It just evaluates to 1 or zero.

Answer (score 1):

Both C and Perl refer to their respective `||` operators as a "logical OR" (as distinct from a bit-wise OR). There's no special name for Perl's behavior of returning the last value as opposed to 0 or 1.

Answer (score 0):

In C, `||` is a **Boolean operation**. In Perl it is an **<s>integer</s> type-agnostic operation** which happens to treat the first argument as a Boolean value. That is the only distinction.

Comment: Sure that it is an integer operation in Perl? What about `$s = "hello" || ""` ?

Comment: @frunsi: Lol, I don't know Perl's type terminology.